# Why can't I import keys into the gnome keyring?

Tags: 14.10, gnome-keyring, certificates, keys

I'm trying to import a private key + certificate into my gnome key ring on Ubuntu 14.10, but the seahorse gui application won't let me, the 'import' button is greyed out:

[image: seahorse import greyed out]

If I try it from the command line, I get the following error:

```
$ gnome-keyring import client.crt 
Gnome2 Key Storage: imported certificate: Test-Client
identifier: 1A9D824585217F1BD54603E83F042F570A2EE9F2

(gnome-keyring:12743): Gck-CRITICAL **: gck_list_unref_free: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (l->data)' failed
```

Trying to import the private key gives me a similar result:

```
$ gnome-keyring import client.key 
Gnome2 Key Storage: imported private key: unknown
identifier: 1A9D824585217F1BD54603E83F042F570A2EE9F2

(gnome-keyring:13026): Gck-CRITICAL **: gck_list_unref_free: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (l->data)' failed
```

How should I import these into my key ring?

(Note that I'm using the openvpn test keys just as an example here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Later I discovered that in spite of the "Gck-CRITICAL" assertion error, this command line commands *did* successfully import the keys.

Why seahorse won't let me import the keys is however still unknown to me.

Comment: I'm trying to add a certificate and I'm running into the same problem as you did. I've been searching but I have no idea how to tell if the certificate was successfully imported, any ideas?

Comment: I did not find a proper way to list the keys using gnome-keyring or seahorse, but openvpn was able to tell me through the pkcs11 API: `openvpn --show-pkcs11-ids /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so`