# How to import certificate so that Chrome can see the cert for HTTPS on localhost

Tags: google-chrome, keyrings, https, gnome-keyring

I am having a similar problem as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/561844/why-cant-i-import-keys-into-the-gnome-keyring)

[image: see image: cannot click import button :(]

For some reason it won't let me click "import" - the button is grayed out.

I also tried doing this:

```
gnome-keyring import certs/rootCA.pem
```

but I got:

```
gnome-keyring: couldn't find any place to import files
```

ultimately the goal is to get chrome and other browsers to recognize the cert as valid when running servers on localhost.

Comment: here is the link I was reading which demonstrates how to do this on a mac: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec/